# Drupal 9.4.8 Webform Authorization Bug Causing [authz_core:error]...AH01630

Tags: apache-2.4, drupal

I'm fairly new to Drupal, about 4 months experience. Everything was going fine till I started working on a webform over the weekend with a twig "If else statement" when I inadvertently added "'#access_create_roles': - authenticated". Suddenly I was locked out. I knew pretty quickly what I'd done. But now I'm struggling to undo it. I don't have a recent backup. Nor can I access phpmyadmin. My only access is via command line. (Config info AWS Lightsail Bitnami, Drupal v9.4.8, Apache 2.4.54.)

Things I've tried, include Changing the .htaccess to grant all as suggested in posts related to "AH01630: client denied by server configuration"; Reboot; and Cache Clearing.

Below please find a copy of the error in the Apache log.

[Wed Jan 25 00:08:02.692763 2023] [authz_core:error] [pid 1450417:tid 140208628442880] [client ###.##.##.78:44162] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /opt/bitnami/drupal/.env

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you for your help!
Mya

Comment: I would suggest [the Drupal Answers SE site](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/). Unless you have modified server config files this is Drupal related, not Apache related...

Comment: Okay, thank you.  I will do that.